# javascript websockets - control initial connection/when does onOpen get bound

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

Two related questions that may be more rooted in my lack of knowledge of how/if browsers pre-parse javascript:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://ws.my.url.com");
ws.onOpen = function() { ... };
```

There appears to be no way to directly control the initialisation of a `WebSocket`, beyond wrapping it in a callback, so I assume the connection is created as soon as the javascript code is loaded and get to the constructor?

When does the `onOpen` property get attached to `ws`? Is there any possibility of a race condition (if for some reason you had some code in between the definition of the socket and the definition of `onOpen`?) so that `onOpen` is undecidably bound before/after the connection is established (I know you could optionally check `ws.readyState`). Supplementary to this, is the WebSocket handshake blocking?

I realise it's all a draft at the moment, possibly implementation dependent and I may have missed something blindingly obvious, but I couldn't see anything particular pertinent on my internet searches/skim through the draft w3c spec, so any help in my understanding of websockets/javascript's inner workings is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

JavaScript is single threaded which means the network connection can't be established until the current scope of execution completes and the network execution gets a chance to run. The scope of execution could be the current function (the `connect` function in the example below). So, you could miss the `onopen` event if you bind to it very late on using a setTimeout e.g. in this example you can miss the event:

View: http://jsbin.com/ulihup/edit#javascript,html,live

Code:

```
var ws = null;

function connect() {
  ws = new WebSocket('ws://ws.pusherapp.com:80/app/a42751cdeb5eb77a6889?client=js&version=1.10');
  setTimeout(bindEvents, 1000);
  setReadyState();
}

function bindEvents() {
  ws.onopen = function() {
    log('onopen called');
    setReadyState();
  };
}

function setReadyState() {
  log('ws.readyState: ' + ws.readyState);
}

function log(msg) {
  if(document.body) {
    var text = document.createTextNode(msg);
    document.body.appendChild(text);
  }
}

connect();
```

If you run the example you may well see that the 'onopen called' log line is never output. This is because we missed the event.

However, if you keep the `new WebSocket(...)` and the binding to the `onopen` event in the same scope of execution then there's no chance you'll miss the event.

For more information on `scope of execution` and how these are queued, scheduled and processed take a look at John Resig's post on [Timers in JavaScript](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/).

Comment: The ctor could invoke the event... Is this documented not to occur?

Comment: @usr The API [spec states](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/#handler-websocket-onopen) that the `onopen` event should be triggered when "the WebSocket connection is established". As per the first para of my answer, this can only happen after the scope of execution completes (the code that invoked the constructor). It would be a fundamental flaw if the `onopen` could be triggered before the developer had a chance to bind to the `onopen` event.

Comment: **facepalm** Seriously?? **sigh** Not doubting you, just floored that it was done this way. Why on earth didn't they provide a configuration object like nearly every JavaScript library does for object creation...

Comment: I just found that I lack some basic understanding of the javascript engine before reading the article at the end of your answer.

Comment: i have 2 plites, one even though javascript is single threaded, it can and often is asynchronous, and has to be treated similarly to as if it might as well been multi-threaded. The other thing is the hoisting thing, it hoists variable declarations/definitions to the top so that the onopen should be defined. I wonder does the websocket constructor call onopen? Seems like it does?

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR - The standard states that the connection can be opened "while the [JS] event loop is running" (e.g. by the browser's C++ code), but that firing the `open` event must be queued to the JS event loop, meaning any `onOpen` callback registered in the same execution block as `new WebSocket(...)` is guaranteed to be executed, even if the connection gets opened while the current execution block is still executing.**

---

According to [The WebSocket Interface](http://web.archive.org/web/20200401050607/https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-sockets.html#the-websocket-interface) specification in the HTML Standard (emphasis mine):

> The `WebSocket(url, protocols)` constructor, when invoked, must run these steps:
>
> 1. Let `urlRecord` be the result of applying the URL parser to `url`.
> 2. If `urlRecord` is failure, then throw a "`SyntaxError`" `DOMException`.
> 3. If `urlRecord`'s scheme is not "`ws`" or "`wss`", then throw a "`SyntaxError`" `DOMException`.
> 4. If `urlRecord`'s fragment is non-null, then throw a "`SyntaxError`" `DOMException`.
> 5. If `protocols` is a string, set `protocols` to a sequence consisting of just that string.
> 6. If any of the values in `protocols` occur more than once or otherwise fail to match the requirements for elements that comprise the value of Sec-WebSocket-Protocol fields as defined by *The WebSocket protocol*, then throw a "`SyntaxError`" `DOMException`.
> 7. **Run this step in parallel:**
>
>    1. **Establish a WebSocket connection given urlRecord, protocols, and the entry settings object. [FETCH]**
>
>    *NOTE* If the establish a WebSocket connection algorithm fails, it triggers the fail the WebSocket connection algorithm, which then invokes the close the WebSocket connection algorithm, which then establishes that the WebSocket connection is closed, which fires the close event as described below.
> 8. Return a new WebSocket object whose url is urlRecord.

Note the establishment of the connection is run 'in parallel', and [the specification further states](http://web.archive.org/web/20200401050607/https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#in-parallel) that "...**in parallel means** those steps are to be run, one after another, **at the same time as other logic in the standard (e.g., at the same time as the event loop)**. This standard does not define the precise mechanism by which this is achieved, be it time-sharing cooperative multitasking, fibers, threads, processes, using different hyperthreads, cores, CPUs, machines, etc."

Meaning that the connection *can* theoretically be opened before `onOpen` registration, even if `onOpen(...)` is the next statement after the constructor call.

However... the standard goes on to state under [Feedback from the protocol](http://web.archive.org/web/20200401050607/https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-sockets.html#feedback-from-the-protocol):

> When the WebSocket connection is established, the user agent **must queue a task to run these steps**:
>
> 1. Change the `readyState` attribute's value to `OPEN` (1).
> 2. Change the `extensions` attribute's value to the extensions in use, if it is not the `null` value. [WSP]
> 3. Change the `protocol` attribute's value to the subprotocol in use, if it is not the `null` value. [WSP]
> 4. **Fire an event named `open` at the `WebSocket` object.**
>
> ***NOTE* Since the algorithm above is queued as a task, there is no race condition between the WebSocket connection being established and the script setting up an event listener for the open event.**

So in a browser or or library that adheres to the HTML Standard, a callback registered to `WebSocket.onOpen(...)` is guaranteed to execute, **if** it is registered before the end of the execution block in which the constructor is called, and before any subsequent statement in the same block that releases the event loop (e.g. `await`).

Comment: *"any `onOpen` callback registered in the same execution block as `new WebSocket(...)` is **guaranteed to be executed**"* - This clears everything, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

@[leggetter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/39904/leggetter) is right, following code did executes sequentially:

```
(function(){
    ws = new WebSocket("ws://echo.websocket.org");
    ws.addEventListener('open', function(e){
        console.log('open', e);
        ws.send('test');
    });
    ws.addEventListener('message', function(e){console.log('msg', e)});

})();
```

But, in [W3C spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/#the-websocket-interface) there is a curious line:

> Return a new WebSocket object, and continue these steps in the background (without blocking scripts).

It was confusing for me, when I was learning browser api for it. I assume that user agents ignoring it, or I misinterpreting it.

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention to the fact that I/O may occur within the scope of execution.
For example, in the following code

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/WebSockets/example");
alert("Hi");
ws.onopen = function(){
    writeToScreen("Web Socket is connected!!" + "<br>");
};
function writeToScreen(message) {
    var div = document.getElementById('test');
    div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', message );
}
```

, the message `"Web Socket is connected"` will appear or not, depending how much time it took you to close the `"Hi"` alert

Comment: I tried this in Chrome v53 and it doesn't matter how long it takes me to close the alert, I never miss the `onopen` event. Did you test this? is it different from browser to browser?

Comment: I just tried this on chrome, and I have the same result as @WayneUroda. You can never miss the `onopen` event with the code in this answer. [ipetrik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61232736/10038051) above explains this behavior in detail.

Answer (score 1):

No actual I/O will happen until after your script finishes executing, so there should not be a race condition.

Comment: So the code sets up `ws` whilst it's loading, sets up `onOpen` and executes the connection once it's finished loading the entire js file?

What if the code was wrapped in a function so that I could create multiple socket connections on the fly after the script is loaded with, eg.

    function(i) { ws = new WebSocket("ws://url.com/" + i);ws.onOpen(...);}

It justs seems like the declaration order is out of sync with the initialisation order.