# The mechanics of the JavaScript WebSockets API

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, websocket

I've been trying to understand some code used to open a websocket:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://my.domain.com');
ws.onopen = function(event) {
    ...
}
```

My question is how does the handshaking get started?  If it is started in the WebSocket constructor, then how does onopen get called if it isn't set by then?  If the WebSocket constructor creates a thread that does the handshaking, then does onopen have to be defined quickly enough before the handshaking is over?  If so, that sounds a little dangerous because if the JS virtual machine is slowed the handshaking could be finished before onopen is defined, which means that the event is not handled.  Or does setting the onopen function trigger the handshaking?

Could someone explain to me the mechanics of the API please?

Comment: You're missing a point that your instantiation and properties' setting are synchronous while the connection is asynchronous. Still an interesting question in case someone delays setting the `onopen` parameter intentionally.

Comment: So the WebSocket does create a thread to do the handshaking and exits immediately?  It wasn't clear what was truly happening from looking at example code, and I could not find an explanation anywhere.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté what do you mean by `delays intentionally`? Through `setTimeout`? Then it might be invalid. But if the setting is delayed because of time-consuming synchronous operations no harm will be done.

Comment: @Miszy - how is no harm done if the WebSocket object looks for an onopen function which doesn't exist at that moment in time because the setting is delayed?

Comment: @Miszy Yes I meant with `setTimeout` - other synchronous code shouldn't interfere as you've said. @ OP the handshaking should happen when it successfully connects to the server and upgrades the protocol, no? In that case it will always happen after the execution of all synchronous code following the instantiation of your WS client.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand JavaScript very well (which I don't), but how can it always happen after the execution of all synchronous code, if the handshaking is asynchronous?  What mechanism guarantees this?  If I was doing the same thing in C++, it would not be guaranteed.

Comment: JS is single-threaded - it will execute all synchronous code at once; asynchronous code such as connecting to a server happens "in the background" and when successful will trigger the `onopen` handler as soon as the thread isn't busy. I'm running some profiling on Firefox and Chrome to ensure that.

Comment: By "in the background", do you mean some kind of co-routine emulation of multi-threading?  So the asynchronous would not even start until after the current javascript code finished?  Am I correct in my assumption?

Comment: @Cthutu yes you are. The asynchronous code will not start until the current code is finished. See my answer below.

Comment: Yes, basically that. I'm trying to find some prove of the "asynchronous would not even start until after the current javascript code finished", but it is clear that asynchronous callbacks such as `onopen` will never execute before the synchronous code finishes executing - similarly to what happens when you do `setTimeout(function(){}, 0)`. Just don't confuse it with [JS coroutines](http://syzygy.st/javascript-coroutines/) which are part of JS 1.7 and already implemented in Firefox. `=]`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I guess proof is `alert(1); setTimeout(function(){alert(2)}, 0); alert(3);` (which alerts 1,3,2).

Comment: @bfavaretto Yes, I use `setTimeout(fn, 0)` inside event handlers whenever I need to wait until an event finishes bubbling (waits until the browser default behavior and other event handlers finish handling the event).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It does not look for `onopen` function until end of execution of current (synchronous) code. That is because the connection (and thus calling `onopen` callback) is asynchronous.
Consider:

```
let x = false;
setTimeout(function () {
    x = true
}, 1000);
while(!x){
    console.log('waiting!');
}
```

The `while` loop there will never end but you would probably suspect it'd end after one second.

If you delay the initialisation of `onopen` function by executing time-consuming (but synchronous) code then it is not dangerous. On the other if you `setTimeout` initialisation of `onopen` then there's no guarantee whether it's defined or not at the time the WebSockets connection is ready as you can't be sure which callback will be executed first.

If you were doing the same thing in C++ you'd use threads for that. In JavaScript callbacks mechanism is not thread-based; it just behaves thread-like (see the endless while loop above).

> Single thread executes one code-unit at a time and other code units
>   are queued until the current code unit is finished executing

source: http://www.slideshare.net/clutchski/writing-asynchronous-javascript-101

It's important to understand that even if you `setTimeout` something for 1s it might not execute after *one second* - If the thread is busy it might never get executed.

Thus if you initiate WebSocket connection and run a loop similar to the one above but waiting for the connection to be ready it might never end.

This behaviour might look strange for programmers not familiar with JS. Therefore for readability I define callbacks at the same time or immediately after the functions which need them whenever it's possible.

If you want to explicitly use threads and concurrent execution, read more about [Web Workers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_worker)

**Reference:**

- [How JavaScript Timers Work](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/)
- [Understanding JavaScript timers](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/28/understanding-javascript-timers/)

Comment: Similar question and answer with example code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393092/javascript-websockets-control-initial-connection-when-does-onopen-get-bound

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any setTimeout function. I'm using a library for this and my code looks something like this:

```
var pushstream = new PushStream({
  host: window.location.hostname,
  port: window.location.port,
  modes: "websocket"
});
pushstream.onmessage = _manageEvent;

function _manageEvent(eventMessage) {
  console.log(eventMessage);
}
```

This gave me a hell of an insight on websockets and how to implement a client in Javascript: https://github.com/wandenberg/nginx-push-stream-module/blob/master/misc/js/pushstream.js

And also the server: https://github.com/wandenberg/nginx-push-stream-module/

It's very well documented I hope it helps :)