# Alert inside websocket open event

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have this code that alert("open") is displayed ok.

```js
var webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/WebSocketServerExample/websocketendpoint");
webSocket.onopen = function(message){ alert("open");};
```

But when  I add one more alert after webSocket creation  then the same alert("open")  doesn't appear

```js
var webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/WebSocketServerExample/websocketendpoint");
alert("after websoscket creation");
webSocket.onopen = function(message){ alert("open");};
```

Has it to do with threads?

UPDATE:
If we replace the alert inside onopen event with console.log then again nothing appears in console. This means that all the code inside onopen doesn't run so this leads us to assume that the event is not triggered. Why?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I'm guessing the websocket forms the connection before you ok the first alert. So essentially you're binding the onopen function after the connection has been formed.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of execution is:

1. `var websocket = new WebSocket(...);`
2. `alert("after websoscket creation");`
3. `webSocket.onopen();`
4. `alert("open");`

i.e., the `onopen` callback is executed after your first `alert`.
That means, that the first alert is open while the second is launched, and in the browser, a second alert is blocked when there is already one open.

Comment: But when we have two sequential alerts then appears the second after we accept the first. Why doesn't happen the same now? Is this because the code at onopen event run on different thread on browser?

Comment: Is the code at onopen event runs or not? If it runs then why alert is not queued? Or the code at onopen have been missed out totally and it does not run because onopen event does not fire?

Comment: Try to log to console instead of `alert`. Then you will see exactly what is happening: `webSocket.onopen = function(message){ console.log("ws onopen");};`

Comment: I think that the onopen event code doesn't run because onopen event doesn't fire. First incident: if we replace the alert inside onopen event with console.log then we have nothing in the console as output!Second incident: If we remove the alert between websocket creation and onopen and move it after the onopen event then it will appear this first and then the alert inside onopen event (that shows us that the code run and the second alert is queued!).

Comment: Please remove all alerts and use console.log only. Alert is not the right method to debug the code.

Comment: I replaced the alerts with console.log and now both have appeared!

Comment: As I told you: the second alert is blocked by the browser.

Comment: Wait! Why the alert inside the onopen event is blocked and not queued but is queued when I remove the first alert after the onopen event code?

Comment: Whern you remove the first alert the onopen alert is not queued but executed, I think?

Comment: No. I think. Because none of the code inside onopen is executed (not only the alert). If we add console.log() inside onopen is not executed. So the only explanation is that in this situation the event doesn't fire. So the question is redefined: why the event doesn't fire?

Comment: Because an alert blocks other execution threads, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I think that we missed out the onopen event.
There is 2 links that has to do with this.

[javascript websockets - control initial connection/when does onOpen get bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393092/javascript-websockets-control-initial-connection-when-does-onopen-get-bound)

Also a very good explanation of code execution:https://bytefish.medium.com/the-execution-order-of-asynchronous-functions-in-the-event-loop-ff641dae4f09

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).